# How to combine 2 ndarrays with different dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (123, 3072) array and i need to split it to 5 approximately same folds (approximately, because 123 can't be divided by 5, for example) in order to do a 5-fold cross-validation. scikit-learn is not allowed. I tried to get 2 ndarrays of size (3, 25, 3072) and (2, 24, 3072). Now i need to combine them, but every function i try raises this:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation 
axis must match exactly
```

Is it possible to concatenate them?

This is my code:

```
num_folds = 5
mod = binary_train_X.shape[0] % num_folds
first_records = (binary_train_X.shape[0] - mod) // num_folds + 1
last_records = first_records - 1
first_part = binary_train_X[:mod * first_records].reshape([mod, first_records, -1])
second_part = binary_train_X[mod * first_records:].reshape([num_folds - mod, last_records, -1])
folds_X = np.concatenate((first_part, second_part))
```

Or maybe there is another way to split it into 5 parts(folds)?

Comment: Is your question about how to combine these two arrays, or to do cross validation without sci-kit? I'm also a bit perplexed as to why you wanted, assuming its correct, to split a (123, 3072) array into a (3, 25, 3072) and a (2, 24, 3072) array (why make a 2d array into a 3d one? Also those numbers do not add up).

Comment: @EvanMata, my question is how to combine them. Or whether there is an another way to get 5 folds of training data of approximately same size. Because, 123, for example, can't be divided by 5.

Comment: You could reshape the arrays to 2d, (75,3072) and ((48,3072), and then concatenate on axis 0.  The numbers add up to 123.

Comment: @hpaulj, so we get an array (123, 3072), which we had in the beginning?

Comment: Yes, we would.  Isn't that what you want?  That's the only combination that makes sense to me.  Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @hpaulj, yeah. My bad for explaining unclearly. I have a (123, 3072) array and i need to split it to 5 approximately same folds (approximately, because 123 can't be divided by 5, for example) in order to do a 5-fold cross-validation. I thought to do it like described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something very similar to this, if not exactly this.

```
def k_fold(array, num_folds): #New to WOS
    #Splits along axis 0 of array
    folds = []
    start = 0
    step = array.shape[0]/num_folds
    for i in range(num_folds):
        end = int(start + step)
        start = int(start)
        fold = array[start:end]
        rest_of_array = np.concatenate((array[:start],array[end:]), axis = 0)
        start = end
        folds.append((fold, rest_of_array))
    return folds
```

Comment: There might be some off-by-one errors, I didn't really both to check.

Comment: in this case we miss the last 3 arrays because 123 can't be divided by 5

Comment: Just do something after the for loop thats like remaining = array[end:] and then distributes the remaining. Alternatively, maybe try having end = rounded up start + step

Answer (score 0):

Since `377856 (123*3072)` is not divisible by `15360 (5*3072)` (123 is not divisible by 5), it is only possible to create 5 equal slices of 3072 by either truncating or padding to a multiple of `15360 (5*3072)`.

Truncating creates shape `(5, 24, 3072)` by discarding values from the end until it aligns:

```python
folds = binary_train_X.flatten()[:np.prod(binary_train_X.shape)//(5*3072)*(5*3072)].reshape(5, -1, 3072)
# this discards 9216 (3072*3) values
```

Padding creates shape `(5, 25, 3072)` by appending zeros to the end until it aligns:

```python
folds = np.pad(binary_train_X.flatten(), (0, -(-np.prod(binary_train_X.shape)//(5*3072))*(5*3072)-np.prod(binary_train_X.shape)), 'constant').reshape(5, -1, 3072)
# this appends 6144 (3072*2) zeros
```

Comment: If i do like this, i get a (123, 3072) array, which i had started with from the beginning. But i need to connect them by first coordinate somehow.

Comment: From your question, I assumed you wanted a 2D array, with the original dimensions. If my assessment is incorrect, please tell what shape you are looking for? What do you mean by "first coordinate"? Or is it the internal order within `first_part` and `second_part` that's important?

Comment: i mean i managed to split the original array(binary_train_X) into 2 arrays: (3, 25, 3072) and (2, 24, 3072). I need to concatenate them somehow to get a one 3-dimensional array of size (5, *, 3072). Original idea is: I need to split binary_train_X to 5 approximately same folds (approximately, because 123 can't be divided by 5, for example) in order to do a 5-fold cross-validation. Thing described above is my vision of doing it. It may be wrong, that's why i need some advise.